# How do I save a form with CreateView

Tags: python, django

I have a `CreateView` and inside this `CreateView` there is a `form_valid()` function. It gets the user_id and assigns it to the user that's logged in user id. The user is basically creating their own question and user_id is a foreign key.

```
class QuestionCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Questions
    form_class = CreatePost

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user_id = self.request.user.id
        return redirect("oauth:profile", username=self.request.user)
```

When I go to the URL of this view, I can see the view and when I try to submit a question it redirects me to the profile. However, the question is not saved in the database. I've tried inserting `form.save()` below the first line in `form_valid` and it does get saved in the table correctly, however, I don't get redirected to the profile, instead I get an error that states `connection error` what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you call `form.save()` before the return statement it should work. If it doesn’t, you’ll need to provide more info about how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I get this error: `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)
[11/Apr/2018 19:03:12] "POST /forum/post/ HTTP/1.1" 500 226230`

Comment: That’s not enough info, you need to show the full traceback. Also your redirect should probably use `username=self.request.user.username`

Comment: @Alasdair I found out why it wasn't working. It's very strange, but it was because I'm using an Elasticsearch search engine and Elasticsearch wasn't running